# flutter android cannot build due to errors in styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, flutter

I cannot build an Android app but iOS app works fine.
This is my styles.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The error is :

***Resource and asset merger: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.***

I do not know where I went wrong, and I really need an answer to publish my app!
Please help me!

Comment: I do not know. I think it is generated by flutter since I never edit this file

Comment: I tried, but it shows me more errors. After several tries, I gave up. I regenerate the system file and put my code in it. Then, it works!